# Can't redirect interactive shell's output to file with a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I trying to write simple output logger. And it's just refuse to work. I can swear, it worked once and it was beautiful.

It's practice, so I don't want to use pre-build bash tools. (like `script`)

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# create_log.sh

exec 6>&1

exec &> log

s

a=0

while true
do    
    sleep 1

    echo love

    ((a++))
    if  [ "$a" -eq 1000 ]
    then 
        break
    fi

done

exec 1>&6 6>&-

echo "Stopped doing love"
```

I run this script in console `. /create_log.sh &`

And as long as the cycle turns, `stdout` and `stderr` should be redirected to log file. But they simply doesn't.

Log file full of ***love***, but I simply can not get date. (or any other output from console)

P.S. If I just type `exec > log` in console it's work perfectly.

Comment: Huh? Of course they are redirected, that's why your log file is full of `love`.

Comment: Or do you expect *some other* process (such as the shell you ran this from) to have *its* output redirected, as opposed to the output from the script and the processes it runs? If so... err... UNIX doesn't work that way; each process table entry that isn't a lightweight thread has its own file descriptor table that's inherited from its parent at startup time but otherwise independent.

Comment: This holds true even for `script` -- it runs a new shell as a subprocess and redirects the output of that shell (though it also plays some TTY tricks), it doesn't change where the output of the parent shell that started it goes.

Comment: Due to the `&`, this runs in a subshell and therefore doesn't affect anything in your current shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, gush! But is it some how possible to have redirected output of root shell? Without `script` magic, I mean?

Comment: @user3582859, why do you expect that to be possible at all?

Comment: @user3582859, ...I mean, you can `source` a script that runs code inside the current shell, or run a shell function locally in the native script, but you can't do it from a subprocess without things that are tremendously ugly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well, it's complicated question. First, I believe in magic, second, I need this very bad, third, I know nothing about Unix. Not so complicated I guess.

Comment: What *exactly* is the "this" that you need? If you specified your question in enough detail to understand your requirements (which probably *don't* require a subprocess to be involved, even though the only things you've discussed -- `script` and `my_function &` -- do use subprocesses), then we could answer it appropriately.

Comment: I thought what `. /script_name.sh` <- same to `source /script_name.sh`?

Comment: Yes. It's not the `. ./script_name.sh` that's a problem, it's the `&` that's the problem.

Comment: btw, if it's written to use bashisms (and thus can only be successfully sourced by bash), it should be `.bash`, not `.sh` -- otherwise you're implying POSIX sh compatibility.

Comment: As-edited, does my answer make this clear?

Comment: Yes, it does. You da real MVP! When the Internet can transmit hugs, you'll gonna be my second target! (my grand ma first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach needs to be run natively in the shell for which you intend to redirect output, not in any subprocess of that shell. Running anything with a `&` as the command separating it from the next command puts it in a subprocess, rather than running in the shell itself.

Consider this pair of functions (for bash 4.1 or newer):

```
# for this example, consider this content to belong to file-with-functions.bash

start_redir() {
    exec {orig_stdout}>&1
    exec > >(tee log >&$orig_stdout)
}

end_redir() {
    [[ $orig_stdout ]] || {
      echo "Not redirected with start_redir previously" >&2
      return 1
    }
    exec 1>&$orig_stdout
    exec {orig_stdout}>&-
}
```

...this can be used as follows:

```
. ./file-with-functions.bash # source these functions into the current shell; no &

start_redir
ls
end_redir
```

You can put these functions in a file that you source, but that sourcing needs to be done in the *foreground*, as putting anything in the background makes it happen in a subprocess, not the shell you're using itself.